# Converting large CSV to JSON in AWS Lambda using python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, csv, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which takes an incoming csv file and converts it to JSON. But this is only working on a small file. When I tested with a large file (1GB) it failed with an out of disk space error. I've been searching for ways around this and have read about the boto streaming option. But I'm struggling with how to code for this, since I'm very new to python. Can anyone give me some pointers with this?

Are there any better ways to accomplish my task...converting a large csv to json in lambda using python. Thanks!!

```
        s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        data = s3_object['Body'].read()
        contents = data.decode('utf-8')
        
        print(type(filename_csv))
        print(type(key))
        
        with open(filename_csv, 'a') as csv_data:
           csv_data.write(contents)
        
        with open(filename_csv) as csv_data:
            csv_reader = c1.DictReader(csv_data)
            
            with open(filename_json, 'a') as output_file:
                for csv_row in csv_reader:
                    json.dump(csv_row, output_file)
                    output_file.write('\n')
            
        with open(filename_json, 'r') as json_file_contents:
            response = s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=keyname_s3, Body=json_file_contents.read())
```

Comment: This is incomplete lambda code. Where are these variables come from?

Comment: Be aware that [EFS is an option](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/), if not quite as simple or cheap as a standalone Lambda function.

Comment: Using EFS  for on-disk buffer that doesn't need to exist in the first place, would be a sledgehammer to crack an egg.  There's no reason the entire CSV or JSON has to be stored all at once in memory, let alone on disk.  @ak2021, you should stream the data https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-dump-in-python/

Comment: FYI your current code doesn't actually generate a JSON file, technically. It generates a file that has multiple lines of text, each of which itself is JSON. The aggregate file itself is not valid JSON.

Comment: @DanielFarrell could you point to an example of how this can be done through streaming?

Comment: @Marcin I'm only showing the relevant portion of my code, I have defined the variables outside of what I'm showing here. :)

Comment: Try https://kokes.github.io/blog/2018/07/26/s3-objects-streaming-python.html